# How to create an ID, based on the minimum unique length of grouped columns?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` similar to this one:

```
set.seed(175232)
DT <- data.table( AU2 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, T), INST= sample(LETTERS[1-5], 10), 
                  ZIP = replicate(10, paste0(sample(LETTERS[1:2],1), sample(10:15,1), collapse="")),
                  CU =  replicate(10, paste0(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 2), collapse = "" )))
DT[,AID1:= .GRP, by= AU2]
setkey(DT, AID1)
setorder(DT, AID1)

   AU2 INST ZIP CU AID1
 1:   B    A B11 BC    1
 2:   B    T B12 AC    1
 3:   B    S A13 AC    1
 4:   B    C A12 BC    1
 5:   B    Q B11 BC    1
 6:   B    J B12 BC    1
 7:   B    L A12 AC    1
 8:   C    I A11 BC    2
 9:   A    W A14 CB    3
10:   A    O B12 AB    3
```

I would like to create an `ID`,  based on the length of unique elements in 3 columns, grouped by another column, `AID1`. Notice that in this case, the `AID1` column is apparently redundant, since can be grouped by `AU2`, but I'm using `AID1` latter. Firstly, I output the minimum unique length in each column.

```
sd.cols = c("INST", "ZIP", "CU" )
DT[,  lapply(.SD, function(x){length(unique(x)) })  , by=AID1, .SDcols = sd.cols]

   AID1 INST ZIP CU
1:    1    7   4  2
2:    2    1   1  1
3:    3    2   2  2
```

Then to the minimum column, I can just run

```
DT[,  which.min(lapply(.SD, function(x){length(unique(x)) }))  , by=AID1, .SDcols = sd.cols]

   AID1 V1
1:    1  3
2:    2  1
3:    3  1
```

That is, for `AID1` 1, the minimum unique length is in column 3, for 2 is 1, and for 3 is 1. Now, taking `AID1` 2 as an example, the minimum length is in column 1, and its value is value in the previous table is 1, that is no duplicates, return its original id `2`. For `ID` 1, the minimum is in column 3, and its length is 2, I would like it to return the `AID1`, plus an addition, 1:2 accordingly to the values in column 2. My approach so far was to write a small function and run it by reference inside the data.table.

```
mk_id <- function(aid1, inst, zip, cu) {
  grp <- list(inst, zip, cu)
  u_grp <- lapply(grp,  function(x) {
    length(unique(x))
  })
  if (any(u_grp == 1)) {
    paste0(aid1)
  } else{
    paste0(aid1, "-", as.integer(factor(grp[[which.min(u_grp)]])) )
  }
}
DT[, ID:= mk_id(AID1, INST, ZIP, CU), by = AID1 ]
DT
    AU2 INST ZIP CU AID1  ID
 1:   B    A B11 BC    1 1-2
 2:   B    T B12 AC    1 1-1
 3:   B    S A13 AC    1 1-1
 4:   B    C A12 BC    1 1-2
 5:   B    Q B11 BC    1 1-2
 6:   B    J B12 BC    1 1-2
 7:   B    L A12 AC    1 1-1
 8:   C    I A11 BC    2   2
 9:   A    W A14 CB    3 3-2
10:   A    O B12 AB    3 3-1
```

Although it's working, I figured out while writing this question, but, for sure there is a more straightforward way.

Comment: There's no good reason to have both AU2 and AID1, the latter being redundant / an integer alias... I think I may have mentioned this last time. Also, when I run your code, I see a different result than the one you display, having 7 B rows. Finally, your function at the end does not work since there is no AC1.

Comment: Those are really typos, sorry. I will correct them.

Comment: @Frank, you deleted the tables, is that to improve clarity, I shouldn't paste them?

Comment: Your tables were showing the wrong data, as I mentioned in the last comment. I think it's better with the tables in, but not if you have them showing confusing/wrong content.

Comment: @Frank, I corrected the typos, and ran again the tables. There was no issue with the data, just redaction.